# Enlightenment WordPress theme submenu showing repeat of menu , How can remove these repitition

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[image]

How can remove the sub menu repetition in dropdown menu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Wordpress admin dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus. Then select the menu that you added in header area. You can add/remove/update the menu items from this page.

Comment: Ok..but  i actually entered like this , means two sub menus but here it showing three sub menus with main menu including , how can i remove these main menu repitition on submenu.

Comment: share a screenshot of menu area and share your website URL